# How to get DocuSIgn Envelope status reports through API call?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to make a report of envelope status. Something like we have in DocuSign console->Envelope Status reports. Which API call can give the counts similar to one in console?

Answer (score 0):

[This API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/envelopes/search/) can be used to get all this information. You can define the criteria and you'll get back a list of envelopes.
See a code example with specific steps in 8 languages of how to do this here - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/list-envelope-status-changes.

Note that the web app may be using a different method to do that.

Comment: Can we use the same API as used in DocuSign console as when I call this API it doesn't matches with the one in console. For eg. for one of the accounts I am getting thousands of voided status envelopes in response of the API but on console its nothing or no data at all.

Comment: I'm sorry that API is restricted for internal use only. I can check if we would consider opening it up, but can't promise anything on that front.